# How to deal with a manyToMany relation in the easyAdminBundle from Symfony?

Tags: php, doctrine, many-to-many, easyadmin, symfony5.4

I have a Product Entity and a Category Entity which are linked together by a join table named "Categories_Products".
Both entities contain a CollectionField and are built in ArrayCollection.
For an example, here is the Product Entity with the Category field :

```
class Product
{
  #[ORM\Id]
  #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
  #[ORM\Column(type: 'integer')]
  private $id;
 
#[ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity: Category::class, mappedBy: "products")]
  private Collection $categories;

  public function __construct()
  {
    $this->categories = new ArrayCollection();
  }
public function getCategories(): Collection
  {
    return $this->categories;
  }
  public function addCategory(Category $category): self
  {
    if (!$this->categories->contains($category)) {
      $this->categories[] = $category;
      $category->addProduct($this);
    }
    return $this;
  }
  public function removeCategory(Category $category): self
  {
    if (!$this->categories->contains($category)) {
      $category->removeProduct($this);
    }
    return $this;
  }
```

I would like to add the possibility to add few categories in the product entity, when adding a product. I use the EasyAdminBundle to display my forms.

Here is the field I added in the configureFields function:

```
public function configureFields(string $pageName): iterable
  {
    return [
    TextField::new('name'),
     CollectionField::new('categories')->setFormType(CategoriesType::class),
   ];
  }
```

Knowing that I tried to create my own input form named "CategoriesType :

```
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\Category;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class CategoriesType extends AbstractType
{
  private $entityManager;

  public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager)
  {
    $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
  }

  public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
  {
    $categories = $this->entityManager->getRepository(Category::class)->findAll();

    $choices = [];

    foreach ($categories as $category) {
      $choices[$category->getName()] = $category->getId();
    }

    $resolver->setDefaults([
      'choices' => $choices,
      'multiple' => true,
      'expanded' => true,
      'by_reference' => false,
      'allow_add' => true,
      'allow_delete' => false,
      'delete_empty' => false,
      'entry_options' =>
      ['attr' => ['class' => 'category-box']],
    ]);
  }

  public function getParent()
  {
    return ChoiceType::class;
  }
}
```

When I try to add a product, it returns this error :
"Unable to transform value for property path "categories": Expected an array."

Can someone explain me how can I cope with EasyAdmin and manyToMany relation please ?

I tried to modify the Field in EasyAdmin : Instead of CollectionField, I tried only "Field". And it returned :  "The Doctrine type of the "categories" field is "8", which is not supported by EasyAdmin."

and same error when I did this :

```
 Field::new('categories', DoctrineEntityType::class)
                ->setFormTypeOptions([
                    'class' => Category::class,
                    'multiple' => true,
                ])
                ->setFormTypeOption('by_reference', false),
```